# Search display controller disappears on multiple clicks on cancel button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UITableView in which i have added UISearchDisplayController on the header of the table view in xib.
When i run the project and click on search bar textfield which show cancel button. When i click on cancel button multiple times frequently then UISearchBar is disappear from the header of the table view.
You can download the sample app from below url.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ero6u76dceq4r7/SearchBarSample.zip?dl=0

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Shubham! Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You have taken the search bar inside tableview. Just take it out of the tableview. Search bar should be above in list. The problem will be resolved.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY01X.png)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i need search bar on the table view header.